# TFS: checkout from one server, checkin to another

Tags: tfs

I've got a need to checkout an entire source tree out of one server and check it into another server.  I'm attempting to script this into a final builder script, but am running into some snags.  I'm able to check everything out, but when I attempt to check it into the new server it tells me there are no pending changes.  Obviously I'm missing something if this is even possible.

Anyone done something similar to this or know of a way I might accomplish this?

One more thing, if the src is empty on server 2 would I have to manually add the files before I can update them?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess that the reason that TFS is saying no pending changes is that you haven't checked out the files from Server 2.  This could get kind of ugly using a single directory, so I would recommend trying this:

`Get` (latest or specific version) from server 1 to 
C:\Server1Files...

`Get` and `Check out for edit` everything from server 2 to 
C:\Server2Files...

Copy from C:\Server1iles1\ to C:\Server2Files

`Check in` from C:\Server2Files

I *think* TFS is going to complain if you try to use a single directory here, as it would see the same directory mapped to two different workspaces (even though they're on different instances of TFS).

Comment: I actually unmap/map the workspaces when I do this, but I will give it a shot using two directories.

Comment: How are you handling new files that were checked in to server 1 but don't exist on server 2?

Comment: Chris: That was one point of contention.  We were hoping since the files would have been added to the solution, that they would be added when we checked in pending changes.  But, the more I think about it, I don't think it will work that way.